# App using Splunk Mint crashes on HTC One but works fine on other devices

Tags: android, splunk

I have an Android app that works fine on most popular devices (Galaxy S3, S4, S5, Note 2, Note 3, HTC Desire, Sony Experia Z2), but crashes when running on an HTC One. Strangely, it runs when fine when run on a virtual HTC One in the Genymotion emulator.

I have Bugsense-Splunk Mint baked inside of the app, and I see some Bugsense stuff inside of the error log cat.

Here is the crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
Caused by: com.splunk.mint.network.util.DelegationException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 162.243.163.162/162.243.163.162 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:62)
at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke(Delegator.java:45)
at com.splunk.mint.network.socket.MonitoringSocketImpl.connect(MonitoringSocketImpl.java:118)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:873)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:367)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
at utilities.RSSParserPosts.getXmlFromUrl(RSSParserPosts.java:216)
at utilities.RSSParserPosts.getRSSFeedItems(RSSParserPosts.java:66)
at com.siliconSarl.CardApp.SearchListFragment$LoadThePostsFromInternet.doInBackground(SearchListFragment.java:131)
at com.siliconSarl.CardApp.SearchListFragment$LoadThePostsFromInternet.doInBackground(SearchListFragment.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 162.243.163.162/162.243.163.162 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:56)
... 21 more
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
... 26 more
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is? What is causing the app to crash only on the HTC One?

Comment: Check for network accessibility in your real device!

Answer (score 1):

That is an issue in Splunk Mint. This is from [their website](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintSDKs/latest/SplunkMINTSDKs/DisablenetworkmonitoringforAndroid):

> Note: Currently, there are known compatibility issues with network monitoring and certain external libraries such as OkHttp, resulting in crashes. Splunk is currently working on this issue, but until it is resolved, disable network monitoring entirely if you experience this issue.

To disable network monitoring, use the disableNetworkMonitoring() method before the initAndStartSession(). (I am not sure it will work or not, because I didn't try this solution...)